# How to dynamically adjust fancybox height

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

The new fancybox [v2]  has a function $.fancybox.update() which on browser resize changes the width of the fancybox

However how do i change the height  dynamically ?

Here is my definition

```
$.fancybox({
'autoSize'      : true,
'fixed'         : true,
'padding'       : 0,
'fitToView '        : true,
'onUpdate '     :  function(){
                                                            $.fancybox.update();
                                                            $.fancybox.reposition();

            },

});
```

Comment: I would rather say that `fitToView` adjusts the size of fancybox if browser size changes too. On the other hand `$.fancybox.update()` changes the size of fancybox according to the content inside the box ... in this case `fitToView` should be set to `false` and `autoSize` to `true`. Now explain yourself what do you mean with ` change the height dynamically`

Comment: What if i move the fancy box from a 1360x800 monitor to a smaller 1024x600 the fancybox width adjusts well but the height does not. The lower portion goes out of the window . You need to scroll to view that part

Comment: because `autoSize` is set to `true` and that means that fancybox takes the dimensions from the content itself. If your content is higher than the view port, then fancybox will be too. Try with `autoSize` set to `false`.

Comment: You do realise that `$.fancybox.update()` in the `onUpdate' event will cause an infinite loop and just eat your CPU?